# Expect - wait until process terminate

Tags: telnet, expect

I am completely new in Expect, and I want to run my Python script via Telnet.
This py script takes about 1 minute to execute, but when I try to run it via Telnet with Expect - it doesn't work.

I have this expect simple code:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet <ip_addr>
expect "login"
send "login\r"
expect "assword"
send "password\r"
expect "C:\\Users\\user>\r"
send "python script.py\r"
expect "C:\\Users\\user>\r"
close
```

When I replace script.py with the one with shorter execution time - it works great. Could you tell me what should I change, so I can wait until my script.py process will terminate? Should I use timeout or sleep?

Comment: Please post output from working and non-working solutions.  A network capture could be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about the execution time of the script, then you can add `sleep` or set the `timeout` to the desired value

```
send "python script.py\r"
sleep 60; # Sleeping for 1 min
expect "C:\\Users\\user>"; # Now expecting for the prompt
```

Or

```
set timeout 60;
send "python script.py\r"
expect "C:\\Users\\user>"; # Now expecting for the prompt
```

But, if the time is variant, then better handle the `timeout` event and wait for the prompt till some amount of time. i.e.

```
set timeout 60; # Setting timeout as 1 min;
set counter 0
send "python script.py\r"
expect {
    # Check if 'counter' is equal to 5
    # This means, we have waited 5 mins already.
    # So,exiting the program.
    if {$counter==5} {
        puts "Might be some problem with python script"
        exit 1
    }
    # Increase the 'counter' in case of 'timeout' and continue with 'expect'
    timeout { 
        incr counter;
        puts "Waiting for the completion of script..."; 
        exp_continue; # Causes the 'expect' to run again
    }
    # Now expecting for the prompt
    "C:\\Users\\user>" {puts "Script execution is completed"} 
}
```

Comment: Your counter logic is not quite right: you want to initialize threshold_limit to zero.

Comment: Good. I think the variable name added to my confusion. You call it a "limit" but it's really a counter.

Comment: @glennjackman : Sorry, I missed that too!!!. Earlier, my logic was to have a threshold defined to a limit and have another variable to track the current count and check it with threshold each time. But, I messed up with that with counter logic initialized with zero. Then you came to rescue and I made another plot hole though. :D. Hope, now things are on track :). By the way, thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative: if you don't care how long it takes to complete:

```tcl
set timeout -1
# rest of your code here ...
```